# CMD Compare two numbers from input

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, numbers, compare

I need to compare 2 float numbers but always get stuck on the output... No matter what I input, the output is always the same. I was searching through the Web, found some articles, but none of them helped me. Here is the code

```
    @echo off
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    set /p first = First: 
    set /p second = Second: 
    IF !first! GTR !second! (GOTO One) ELSE (GOTO Two)

    :One
    ECHO first
    GOTO Done

    :Two
    IF !first! LSS !second! (ECHO second) ELSE (ECHO Equal)
    GOTO Done

    :Done
    pause
```

Comment: Read the help for the command you are trying to use.  It will usually have the answer for you.  If you read the help for the SET command you will see that there is NEVER a space before the equals symbol in any of the examples.

Comment: You should note that all Batch commands that manage numbers can only manage _integer_ numbers. If you compare two "float" numbers with `IF` command, the numbers are taken as strings. Try it: `IF 123.456 LSS 2.789 ECHO This is wrong`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set /p first = First:
```

should be

```
set /p first=First:
```

Spaces are significant on both sides of a `set` - the space would be included in the variable name.

Comment: ...however, spaces are **not** significant in a `set /a`

Comment: Yes this is true, however this does not solve the problem.

Comment: OP wants a program that can distinguish which number is higher and display it.

Comment: @PryroTech Sorry for lateness, but this solved my problem.